# Lua - flushing input buffer during interactive terminal session

Tags: lua

So I've got this lua test script for handling interactive user input in the terminal. It's working as expected, except I can't figure out a way to clear the input buffer between calls to io.read(1).

Before you say it, no, curses is not an option, nor is any third-party library. This script will (when it's done) be used on an embedded device with set firmware, so pure lua is the only option.

The code:

```
    UP = 65
    DOWN = 66
    RIGHT = 67
    LEFT = 68

    local function sleep(seconds)
        os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(seconds));
    end

    local function write(String)
        io.write(String);
        io.flush();
    end

    local key = {
        [27] = function()
            group = (io.read(1)):byte();
            if group == 91 then
                direction = (io.read(1)):byte();
                if direction == UP then return write("Up") end
                if direction == DOWN then return write("Down") end
                if direction == RIGHT then return write("Right") end
                if direction == LEFT then return write("Left") end
                return write("("..direction..")");
            end
            return write("("..direction..")");
        end,
        [113] = function() running = false end

    }

    running = true;
    os.execute("stty raw -echo");
    while running do
        local k = io.read(1);
        if k == 'w' then break end
        k = k:byte();
        if key[k] then key[k]();
            else write('('..k..')') end
        sleep(.25);
        -- while io.read(1) ~= nil do end  -- This blocks indefinitely
    end
    os.execute("stty sane")
```

Comment: If `io.flush()`/`io.stdin:flush()` don't work, an `os.execute` hack would be the only possible solution then I think.